# Fullcalendar and json

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, fullcalendar

I'm trying to load events from my database. I'm using GAE, java and JSP. My problem is in the json response. If i write directly in the script the output of my json, it s work correctly, but by ajax call no. This is my method in java:

```
public void caricaDati(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Date start=JavaTimeStampToDateTime(Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("start")));
    Date end=JavaTimeStampToDateTime(Double.parseDouble(req.getParameter("end")));
    Date afterAddingTenMins=new Date(start.getDate() + (10 * 60000));
    ObjectifyService.register(Appuntamento.class);
    List<Appuntamento> listaA= ofy().load().type(Appuntamento.class).filter("d >=", start).filter("d <=", end).list();
    System.out.println(listaA);
    JSONObject j= new JSONObject();
    for(Appuntamento a : listaA){
        resp.setContentType("application/json");  // Set content type of the response so that jQuery knows what it can expect.
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resp.getWriter().write(utilDispensaToJson(a, start, end));
    }
}
```

The method of json:

```
public String utilDispensaToJson(Appuntamento k, Date Start, Date End) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
         sb.append("[");
        sb.append("{");
        sb.append("id : '" + k.getId() + "' , ");
        sb.append("title : '" + k.getTitolo() + "' , ");
        sb.append("start : '" + k.getData() + "' , ");
        //sb.append("\"end\" : \"" + End + "\",");
        sb.append("allDay : false ,");

        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(","));
        sb.append("}");
        sb.append("]");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "errore";
    }

}
```

the output of json is:

[{id : '6473924464345088' , title : 'dfsf' , start : '2014/04/25 08:30' , allDay : false }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output JSON appears to be invalid.

The properties (id, title, start, allday) should be surrounded by double quotes and so are the values that are string types. Here you use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Ref: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jsoncstyleguide.xml#Double_Quotes

Also you can test the validity of your JSON string on this website: http://jsonlint.com/